# Is there a control for Java Swing that is similar to listview in .NET?

Tags: java, swing, listview

I am looking for a control in Java Swing that is similar to this one in .NET.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also consider `Outline`, discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

[image: outline image]

Answer (score 0):

in `Swing` use `JTree` along with `JCheckBox` for what you are looking for.

Use the `JTree` along with the `JTable`. See http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/index.html for reference

Comment: What about group and multiple columns? The control can group items and has multiple colums like the image you see. I think JTree can not do it.

Comment: ofcourse you need `JTable`. Thought, that was evident from your table structure.